# Are there any sects that prohibit the use of images in general?

Tags: denomination-survey, art, iconography

Are there any Christian sects that prohibit the use of images in general (even for art/entertainment)?

Comment: Like, any art, or photos, at all? I can't imagine that to be the case. Why would they? What makes you think this could possibly be the case? Please [edit] this to contextualise your question.

Comment: Please don't use the comment field to answer questions. If you have an answer that lives up to this site's answer guidelines, post it as an answer. Otherwise the comment tool is for suggesting improvements or requesting clarification to posts.

Comment: Do you mean even more restrictive than religious Islamic art, which is mostly non-representational? No images at all, not even abstract ones?

Comment: How do you define "sects"? Islam has long prohibited the use of images in general, which seems to have been based on a questionable interpretation of the First of the Ten Commandments. Don

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  If you have not already done so, please take our Tour which explains what we look for in questions that show evidence of research: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

**I'm going to go out on a limb and say no.**

It's very hard to say that *no* Christians believe something, but in this case I'm prepared to say so. I base this on the fact that there are some very strict sects that are against the use of images for various reasons, but none that ban their use in general.

As a fact there are plenty of conservative Christian groups that prohibit the use of "graven images" in religious settings, but no sizeable ones that ban their use entirely. The most likely candidates would be Old Order Mennonite and Amish groups. They are quite strictly against the use of images in worship and religion. They are also against the use of personal photographs, but not against all images in general.

The prohibition against personal pictures is twofold. They believe that having a picture taken encourages vanity and a concern for ones appearance rather than holiness. One should not keep photographs of family members or friends because they should be remembered for their spiritual attributes rather than their physical appearance.

So while personal pictures are forbidden, other kinds of images are not.